# Defining Secs per year as Macro in C?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

In an MCQ Exam the 2 choices were:
**`#define SEC (60*60*24*365)`**  OR
**`#define SEC (60*60*24*365UL)`**
Is there a difference between the two possibilities that makes one a better choice?

Comment: If you're confident you won't be required to port to a machine with 16-bit `int` types, then the only difference is that the first macro defines a (signed) `int` and the second an `unsigned long`.  The result is well within the range of 32-bit `int` values, so most of the time it will make no difference. The exceptional case would be when you need to multiply a negative difference in years by the number of seconds in a year; then the `unsigned long` will give you an unsigned result (large) where the `int` will give you the expected signed result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constants `60`, `24` and `365` all have type `int`, so multiplying these values will be done in that type too.  The maximum value representable in an `int` is allowed to be as low as 32767, though - so the complete multiplication may overflow.

However, even the version using `365UL` isn't safe.  Because multiplication associates left-to-right, the first multiplication done is `60 * 60` (which is fine), and then the result is multiplied by 24.  The mathematical result of this is 86400, which may already have overflowed an `int`.

A safe option would be:

```
#define SEC (60*60*24L*365)
```

but it would be clearest to make all the constants of type `long`:

```
#define SEC (60L*60L*24L*365L)
```

(This formulation will also be wrong in leap years, and years containing leap seconds).

Comment: Also, you can mention that using `#define SEC 31536000` would have worked because C will use the appropriate signed type that works.

Answer (score 0):

choose the second **#define SEC(60*60*24*365UL)**".

UL means the type of this number unsigned long. As the 60*60*24*365 is very big, it may get overflow error on some compiler

Comment: 31536000 is not all that big; it is well within the bounds of a 32-bit integer type (though it overflows a 16-bit integer type, of course).

Comment: What if this was used on a processor with a short (16 bit) integer type?